# CentOS cannot start munin after install via yum

Tags: centos, munin

I've installed munin (and munin-node) via yum after I did the yum update, this all on CentOS 6.6 - 64bit with directadmin. This all goes well including related packages.

Now when I try to start the munin-node service i get the following error.

```
Starting Munin Node: Base class package "Net::Server::Fork" is empty.
(Perhaps you need to 'use' the module which defines that package first,
or make that module available in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5).
at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Munin/Node/Server.pm line 5
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Munin/Node/Server.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/sbin/munin-node line 36.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/munin-node line 36.
```

Can anybody help me with this error? (my background is more php...)

Comment: What yum repository did enable that contained the munin package(s) you installed?

Comment: @EtanReisner It was a tutorial via a site, cannot recall. How can I check it?

Comment: The output of `yum repolist` might be help. In any case whatever package it was seems to be busted as it does not include the right requirements entries.

Comment: @EtanReisner this is what I have: http://pastebin.com/m94Fi66F

Comment: I'm assuming the package came from rpmforge. What does `rpm -q munin-node` say? Does it include `.rf`? But like I said, the package is broken as it should include a requirement on whatever the perl dependency for `Net::Server::Fork` is. (Unless you forced the `munin-node` install somehow.) Does `yum info perl-Net-Server` return anything?

Comment: @EtanReisner `rpm -q munin-node` gives `munin-node-2.0.24-1.el6.noarch` and here is what yum info says: http://pastebin.com/fgJW5Jhy

Comment: You have `munin-node` from (presumably) EPEL which also contains a `perl-Net-Server` package but you currently have the rpmforce `perl-Net-Server` package installed. I would try updating `perl-Net-Server`.

Comment: @EtanReisner yep that worked! If you can summarize your replies here as an answer, I will accept that one. thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `munin-node` package and the `perl-Net-Server` package (which provides `Net::Server::Fork`) are out of sync. Updating the `perl-Net-Server` package to come from the same repository as the `munin-node` package should help fix things.